# Compare textfield value with database value

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I need help in creating my application, I create a database and connect it to my application my database contain manager table having a id, name, etc of fields. when I enter any id in textfield it must compare the value of textfield with database values how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the id in textField, assuming it is String, using [String#equalsIgnoreCase](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) against the value of id retrieved from database using `JDBC` like shown [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/JDBC-SQLProcessor/Simple_JDBC_Example.shtml). Let me know in case you get stuck anywhere - Good Luck!

Comment: What if the DB has a million of records? Do you really want to copy them all into Java's memory to do the comparison right there? This makes no sense. Utilize the SQL powers to let the DB return **exactly** the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

First learn [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL). It's the language which you're supposed to communicate with the DB in order to retrieve and store data. In this particular case, the key answer is the SQL `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM manager WHERE name = "somename"
```

or if you want to select multiple values, e.g. name and password, use the `AND`:

```sql
SELECT id, name, password FROM manager WHERE name = "somename" AND password = MD5("somepass")
```

It'll return all matching results, which can be zero or one (or even more if you don't have your keys right).

Your next step is to learn [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). It's a Java API which enables you to execute SQL queries using Java code and obtain the results from the DB. In this particular case you'd like to use `PreparedStatement` to set user-controlled values in a SQL query and execute it.

```java
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, password FROM manager WHERE username = ? AND password = MD5(?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [SQL tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.net)
- [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)